# When add content via innerHTML occur unnecessary scoll to the element

Tags: javascript, html

I need to insert some html to node after ajax call in javascript.

I use framework, but it doesn't matter. Important thing - insertion content in ajax callback:

```
// added filterWrapper to DOM
BX.ajax.get(
    '/get_filter_for_diagrams.php',
    {
        'sessid': BX.bitrix_sessid()
    },
    function (data)
    {
        filterWrapper.innerHTML = data;
    }
);
```

After adding content via innerHTML my window scrolls to this element, but I not want this behaviour.

I try make:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

But all the same - scroll to element.

How can I prevent scroll to element?

UPD:
generated html

```html
<!-- Final :: Search -->
<div class="main-ui-filter-search main-ui-filter-no-search main-ui-filter-theme-default" id="filter_diagrams_underwriters_search_container">
 <input
   type="text"
   tabindex="1"autofocus=""value=""
   name="FIND"
   placeholder="Filter"
   class="main-ui-filter-search-filter"
   id="filter_diagrams_underwriters_search"
   autocomplete="off">
 <div class="main-ui-item-icon-block">
  <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-search"></span>
  <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-delete"></span>
 </div>
</div>

<!--'start_frame_cache_xIeC97'-->
<script type="text/html" id="filter_diagrams_underwriters_GENERAL_template">
 <div class="main-ui-filter-wrapper main-ui-filter-value-required-mode main-ui-filter-theme-default">
  <div class="main-ui-filter-inner-container">
   <div class="main-ui-filter-sidebar">
    <div class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-title">
     <h5 class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-title-item">Filters</h5>
    </div><!--main-ui-filter-sidebar-->
    <div class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-container">
                  <div class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item main-ui-hide" data-id="tmp_filter" >
        <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-grab" title="Pull to sort the filters list"></span>
        <span class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-text-container">
         <span class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-text">Current month</span>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Filter name" value="Current month" class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-input">
         <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-pin" title="Default filter"></span>
        </span>
                 <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-pin" title="Default filter"></span>
                <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-edit" title="Edit filter name"></span>
        <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-delete" title="Delete filter"></span>
        <div class="main-ui-filter-edit-mask"></div>
       </div>
             <div class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item main-ui-filter-current-item main-ui-hide" data-id="default_filter" >
        <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-grab" title="Pull to sort the filters list"></span>
        <span class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-text-container">
         <span class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-text">Filter</span>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Filter name" value="Filter" class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-input">
         <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-pin" title="Default filter"></span>
        </span>
                 <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-pin" title="Default filter"></span>
                <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-edit" title="Edit filter name"></span>
        <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-delete" title="Delete filter"></span>
        <div class="main-ui-filter-edit-mask"></div>
       </div>
                <div class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item main-ui-filter-new-filter">
      <div class="main-ui-filter-edit-mask"></div>
      <input class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-edit-control" type="text" placeholder="Filter name">
     </div>
    </div><!--main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-container-->
   </div><!--main-ui-filter-sidebar-->
   <div class="main-ui-filter-field-container">
    <div class="main-ui-filter-field-container-list">

    </div>

    <div class="main-ui-filter-field-add">
     <span class="main-ui-filter-field-add-item">Add field</span>
     <span class="main-ui-filter-field-restore-items">Restore default fields</span>
    </div><!--main-ui-filter-field-add-->
   </div><!--main-ui-filter-field-container-->
   <div class="main-ui-filter-bottom-controls">
         <div class="main-ui-filter-add-container">
      <span class="main-ui-filter-add-item">Save filter</span>
      <span class="main-ui-filter-add-edit" title="Configure filter"></span>
      <span class="main-ui-filter-reset-link">
       <span class="main-ui-filter-field-button-item">Reset to default</span>
      </span>
     </div><!--main-ui-filter-add-container-->
    
    <div class="main-ui-filter-field-preset-button-container">
     <div class="main-ui-filter-field-button-inner">
      <span class="webform-small-button webform-small-button-blue main-ui-filter-field-button main-ui-filter-find">
       <span class="main-ui-filter-field-button-item">Search</span>
      </span>
      <span class="webform-small-button webform-small-button-transparent main-ui-filter-field-button main-ui-filter-reset">
       <span class="main-ui-filter-field-button-item">Reset</span>
      </span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-ui-filter-field-button-container">
     <div class="main-ui-filter-field-button-inner">
             <label class="main-ui-filter-field-button main-ui-filter-save-for-all" for="save-for-all">
        <input id="save-for-all" class="main-ui-filter-field-button-checkbox" type="checkbox">
        <span class="main-ui-filter-field-button-item">Apply for all users</span>
       </label>
            <span class="webform-small-button webform-small-button-accept main-ui-filter-field-button main-ui-filter-save">
       <span class="main-ui-filter-field-button-item">Save</span>
      </span>
      <span class="webform-small-button webform-small-button-transparent main-ui-filter-field-button main-ui-filter-cancel">
       <span class="main-ui-filter-field-button-item">Cancel</span>
      </span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div><!--main-ui-filter-bottom-controls-->
  </div><!--main-ui-filter-inner-container-->
 </div><!--main-ui-filter-wrapper-->
</script>


<!--'end_frame_cache_xIeC97'-->
```

UPD2: after regular expression on remove autofocus (console.log output):

```html
<!-- Final :: Search -->
<div class="main-ui-filter-search main-ui-filter-no-search main-ui-filter-theme-default" id="filter_diagrams_underwriters_search_container">
 <input
   type="text"
   tabindex="1"value=""
   name="FIND"
   placeholder="Filter"
   class="main-ui-filter-search-filter"
   id="filter_diagrams_underwriters_search"
   autocomplete="off">
 <div class="main-ui-item-icon-block">
  <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-search"></span>
  <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-delete"></span>
 </div>
</div>

<!--'start_frame_cache_xIeC97'-->
<script type="text/html" id="filter_diagrams_underwriters_GENERAL_template">
 <div class="main-ui-filter-wrapper main-ui-filter-value-required-mode main-ui-filter-theme-default">
  <div class="main-ui-filter-inner-container">
   <div class="main-ui-filter-sidebar">
    <div class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-title">
     <h5 class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-title-item">Filters</h5>
    </div><!--main-ui-filter-sidebar-->
    <div class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-container">
                  <div class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item main-ui-hide" data-id="tmp_filter" >
        <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-grab" title="Pull to sort the filters list"></span>
        <span class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-text-container">
         <span class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-text">Current month</span>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Filter name" value="Current month" class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-input">
         <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-pin" title="Default filter"></span>
        </span>
                 <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-pin" title="Default filter"></span>
                <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-edit" title="Edit filter name"></span>
        <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-delete" title="Delete filter"></span>
        <div class="main-ui-filter-edit-mask"></div>
       </div>
             <div class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item main-ui-filter-current-item main-ui-hide" data-id="default_filter" >
        <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-grab" title="Pull to sort the filters list"></span>
        <span class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-text-container">
         <span class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-text">Filter</span>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Filter name" value="Filter" class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-input">
         <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-pin" title="Default filter"></span>
        </span>
                 <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-pin" title="Default filter"></span>
                <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-filter-icon-edit" title="Edit filter name"></span>
        <span class="main-ui-item-icon main-ui-delete" title="Delete filter"></span>
        <div class="main-ui-filter-edit-mask"></div>
       </div>
                <div class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-item main-ui-filter-new-filter">
      <div class="main-ui-filter-edit-mask"></div>
      <input class="main-ui-filter-sidebar-edit-control" type="text" placeholder="Filter name">
     </div>
    </div><!--main-ui-filter-sidebar-item-container-->
   </div><!--main-ui-filter-sidebar-->
   <div class="main-ui-filter-field-container">
    <div class="main-ui-filter-field-container-list">

    </div>

    <div class="main-ui-filter-field-add">
     <span class="main-ui-filter-field-add-item">Add field</span>
     <span class="main-ui-filter-field-restore-items">Restore default fields</span>
    </div><!--main-ui-filter-field-add-->
   </div><!--main-ui-filter-field-container-->
   <div class="main-ui-filter-bottom-controls">
         <div class="main-ui-filter-add-container">
      <span class="main-ui-filter-add-item">Save filter</span>
      <span class="main-ui-filter-add-edit" title="Configure filter"></span>
      <span class="main-ui-filter-reset-link">
       <span class="main-ui-filter-field-button-item">Reset to default</span>
      </span>
     </div><!--main-ui-filter-add-container-->
    
    <div class="main-ui-filter-field-preset-button-container">
     <div class="main-ui-filter-field-button-inner">
      <span class="webform-small-button webform-small-button-blue main-ui-filter-field-button main-ui-filter-find">
       <span class="main-ui-filter-field-button-item">Search</span>
      </span>
      <span class="webform-small-button webform-small-button-transparent main-ui-filter-field-button main-ui-filter-reset">
       <span class="main-ui-filter-field-button-item">Reset</span>
      </span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-ui-filter-field-button-container">
     <div class="main-ui-filter-field-button-inner">
             <label class="main-ui-filter-field-button main-ui-filter-save-for-all" for="save-for-all">
        <input id="save-for-all" class="main-ui-filter-field-button-checkbox" type="checkbox">
        <span class="main-ui-filter-field-button-item">Apply for all users</span>
       </label>
            <span class="webform-small-button webform-small-button-accept main-ui-filter-field-button main-ui-filter-save">
       <span class="main-ui-filter-field-button-item">Save</span>
      </span>
      <span class="webform-small-button webform-small-button-transparent main-ui-filter-field-button main-ui-filter-cancel">
       <span class="main-ui-filter-field-button-item">Cancel</span>
      </span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div><!--main-ui-filter-bottom-controls-->
  </div><!--main-ui-filter-inner-container-->
 </div><!--main-ui-filter-wrapper-->
</script>


<!--'end_frame_cache_xIeC97'-->
```

Comment: Altering the contents via innerHTML does not trigger that behaviour (try document.getElementsByClassName('js-primary-footer-links')[0].innerHTML = "<div>HIIIIII</div>" at this site for instance, using console tools). So, its probably something in the framework or in the content (data) itself. Can you share some more info?

Comment: Do `console.log(data)` and add the output into your post.

Comment: Reference to [`BX.ajax.get()`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/js_lib/ajax/bx_ajax_get.php). To note: Site is in Russian. `Right-Click` > `Translate to English`.

Comment: @Alex There is a big html. I add to question description

Comment: @user1515791 I add html content.

Comment: Its the autofocus attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autofocus attribute will make the control, well, autofocus. Thus the page will scroll to there.

To demonstrate, in this actual page (this SO page), try executing (using dev tools console)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('js-primary-footer-links')[0].innerHTML = "<input autofocus='' type='text'/>"
```

VS

```
document.getElementsByClassName('js-primary-footer-links')[0].innerHTML = "<input type='text'/>"
```

Is the generated content also under your control? - if not, you can just remove that part from the returned data, before putting it on the page (using innerHTML)

ie

```
      filterWrapper.innerHTML = data.replace('autofocus=""', '');
```

EDIT: your new code does not trigger the scroll for me anymore, so there is something else then as well. Maybe in the source of your current page, or still something in the framework.

Example with your supplied code (save in test.html and open in browser):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/template" id="content">
             <!-- Put your processed HTML here, for clearity - I did not include it here-->
             <!--Your old html did trigger the scroll, your new html doesnt-->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="load()" value="load"/>
        <div style="background-color: green; height: 100%"></div>
        <div id="diva"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I can edit this html on server side. But what is the 
`js-primary-footer-links`? I don't have element with this class.

Comment: No, thats just an example for this actual page (this SO page) if you run  those commands using some dev tools (F12 -> console) you can see the difference in behavior on this page.

Comment: ok, I execute you regular expression on js side and autofocus attribute is removed (i see new html), but scoll still exist.

Comment: Are you sure that the autofocus attribute is really removed from the html? I am not sure on the quotes. If you inspect the resulting html, is the attribute really gone? (console.log(data.replace('autofocus', ''))

Comment: Yes I ctrl+F on autofocus in new html, and it's removed. I add new html in question description

Comment: You are right. I find another one attribute autofocus in some js. I remove it and scroll is disappeared!